# Using $ionicPopup in external .js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am making a simple shopping list application with Ionicframework and AngularJS. Now I have app.js file and external .js file:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('shoppingList', ['ionic']);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $ionicPopup) {
    $scope.shoppingList = new shoppingList();
})
```

**shoppingList.js**

```
function shoppingList(ionicListDelegate) {
    this.items = [];
}

shoppingList.prototype.addItem(item) {
    this.items.push(item);
}
```

I am trying to use Ionic Popup service (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/) in my shoppingList.js file and I am thinking how to do it. Can I pass $ionicPopup to shoppingList like this: `$scope.shoppingList = new shoppingList($ionicPopup);`?

Is this even good way to do application like this, or is it better to use service?

Comment: `shoppingList` service would make more sense, it would also be simple to manage dependency injection.